# Control and cancel multiple tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I've tried to code simple WinForm app, and i have some problem with its behavior.
The purpose is to draw small rectangles on the panel with two optional colors (red & black). There is 4 buttons - pair for each color - **Draw red**, **Stop red**, **Draw black**, **Stop Black**.

When the **Draw** button clicked, new task of **DrawRectangles** is generated.
When the **stop** button clicked, the task will be cancelled, using CancellationTokenSource.

The problem is: when i've created many tasks (i.e 3 tasks of Draw red) and after that i pressed on stop button, it canceled just the first task and I could not cancel the other tasks (Draw red tasks') and they ran endless.

The code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cnDrawRedToken;
    CancellationTokenSource cnDrawBlackToken;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e{}

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){}

    private void RedBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunDrawingTask(SetSpecificPen(Color.Red),out this.cnDrawRedToken);           
    }

    private async Task DrawRectangles(int height, int width, Random random, Rectangle rectangle, Pen blackPen, CancellationToken cnToken)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (cnToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            rectangle.x = random.Next(0, width);
            rectangle.y = random.Next(0, height);
            this.panel1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(blackPen, rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
            //Thread.Sleep(200);
            await Task.Delay(150);
        }
    }

    private Pen SetSpecificPen(Color color)
    {
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(color, 2);
        return blackPen;
    }

    private Rectangle InitRectangleWidthAndHeights()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

        rectangle.width = 10;
        rectangle.height = 10;
        return rectangle;
    }

    private void StpRedBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cnDrawRedToken != null)
        {
            this.cnDrawRedToken.Cancel();
            this.cnDrawRedToken = null; 
        }
        else
        {
            this.cnDrawRedToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
    }

    private void BlackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunDrawingTask(SetSpecificPen(Color.Black),out this.cnDrawBlackToken);
    }

    private void StpBlkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cnDrawBlackToken != null)
        {
            this.cnDrawBlackToken.Cancel();
            this.cnDrawBlackToken = null; 
        }
    }

    private void RunDrawingTask(Pen specificPen, out CancellationTokenSource cnTokenSource) 
    {
        int height = this.panel1.Height;
        int width = this.panel1.Width;
        Random random = new Random();
        Rectangle rectangle = InitRectangleWidthAndHeights();

        cnTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationTokenSource cts = cnTokenSource;
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DrawRectangles(height, width, random, rectangle, specificPen, cts.Token), cts.Token);
    }
}
```

What i want to do is when i click on **Stop** button all the running tasks of the same color will be cancelled.

**UPDATE:**
As Fabio suggested, i've rewrote my click's methods as well as the affected methods. After that chenges it works as desired.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cnDrawRedToken = new CancellationTokenSource() ;
        cnDrawBlackToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
 private void RedBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cnDrawRedToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           this.cnDrawRedToken = null;
           this.cnDrawRedToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }           
        RunDrawingTask(SetSpecificPen(Color.Red), this.cnDrawRedToken);           
    }
private void StpRedBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cnDrawRedToken != null)
        {
            this.cnDrawRedToken.Cancel();
        }          
    }

    private void BlackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cnDrawBlackToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.cnDrawBlackToken = null;
            this.cnDrawBlackToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }             
        RunDrawingTask(SetSpecificPen(Color.Black), this.cnDrawBlackToken);
    }

    private void StpBlkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.cnDrawBlackToken != null)
        {
            this.cnDrawBlackToken.Cancel();                
        }
    }

    private void RunDrawingTask(Pen specificPen, CancellationTokenSource cnTokenSource) 
    {
        int height = this.panel1.Height;
        int width = this.panel1.Width;
        Random random = new Random();
        Rectangle rectangle = InitRectangleWidthAndHeights();

        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DrawRectangles(height, width, random, rectangle, specificPen, cnTokenSource.Token), cnTokenSource.Token);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that if you click 3 times the button that runs the tasks, you're going to run 3 tasks with 3 different cancellation token sources.

Because of this line in `RunDrawingTask`, you will overwrite the cancellation token that you just passed to `RunDrawingTask`

```
cnTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

If you remove that line, you will pass the same token every time, and all your tasks will be able to react to the cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i will take your solution it will lead to other problem. If after **stop** clicking i want to continue the drawing and clicks again on **Draw red** i have to renew the CancellationTokenSource (that was canceled) for all the new Draw red tasks. Where i will put this code `cnTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();`?

Comment: In the `RedBtn_Click` and `BlackBtn_Click` method, you can observe the property `IsCancellationRequested` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.iscancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) of the appropriate `CTS`. If it is set to true, you can create a new instance of the Cancellation Token Source, set the appropriate field, and pass it to the `RunDrawingTask` method.

Comment: Salalai Thanks. Now, after rewrite `click` methods it works good! I'll update my question with the rewritten methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is invalid for your requirements. One of solutions: 
you need to create two CancelationTokenSources: `redCancelationTokenSource` and `blackCancelationokenSource`. And rewrite `RunDrawingTask` method like this:

> ```
>     private void RunDrawingTask(Pen pen, out CancellationTokenSource cnTokenSource)
>     {
>         int height = panel1.Height;
>         int width = panel1.Width;
>         Random random = new Random();
>         Rectangle rectangle = InitRectangleWidthAndHeights();
>
>         var cts = pen == blackPen ? blackTokenSource : redTokenSource;
>         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DrawRectangles(height, width, random, rectangle, pen, cts.Token), cts.Token);
>     }
>
>     CancellationTokenSource blackTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
>     CancellationTokenSource redTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
>
>     Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
>     Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
> ```

and when you want to stop draw action you must call 'Cancel' method on one of CancelationTokenSources: redCancelationSource or blackCancelationSource.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in your example, but cancelling the specified cnTokenSource will not have any effect on blackTokenSource  and redTokenSource  here, right ?

Comment: No, you wrong. Look in all app we have only two cts. In this line
`var cts = pen == blackPen ? blackTokenSource : redTokenSource` we detect, which cts we must use right now (depends on pen). So if you send redPen - will ctrating a new Task with `redCancelationToken`. So, when you cancel `RedCancelationTokenSource` all tasks with this cts will aborted. Ok??